# Updating each thread's timer in a TListView without CPU overload

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2007

**Delphi used:** 2007

Hello everyone,

I have a TListView with `ViewStyle` set to `vsReport`. When I click on a button, I launch about 50 threads. Each thread has a `TListItem` component. Each `TListItem` has a `SubItem` that is a timer. It starts at 250 and goes all the way down to 0. The user is able to see each timer decreasing in the TListView.

I have written the following code:

```
procedure TThreadWorker.DeleteTickets;
begin
 ListItem.Delete;
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.UpdateTimer;
begin
 ListItem.SubItems[1] := IntToStr(Timer);
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.TimerCounter;
begin
 Timer := 300;
 repeat
  Sleep(1000);
  Dec(Timer);
  Synchronize(UpdateTimer);
 until (Timer = 0);
 Synchronize(DeleteTickets);
end;
```

And... it works! But here's the thing: all these synchronizations seem to unnecessarily overload the CPU. Obviously, it's a bigger problem when I launch more threads (100, 200 or 300) or when I use a weaker computer. At first, I wasn't sure it was the synchronizations; but if I deactivate them, the CPU is no more overloaded.

To be frank, it's not *that* much of an issue. However, I have the feeling that decrementing timers shouldn't cause any sort of CPU overload: my code is probably not right. I tried calling `UpdateTimer` less often, and while it softens the CPU overload, it doesn't fix it in the end. Furthermore, I'd like the user to see the timer updated *each* second. The timer also needs to be as precise as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Don't use 50 threads, you probably don't have 50 cores.
2) Use messaging, for example use Queue instead of Synchronize.

Comment: @gabr 50 (most time sleeping) threads are not the problem, but synchronization (every thread nearly at the same time) with the mainthread and forcing the VCL to repaint the ListView. Your 1) is wrong in this case

Comment: @gabr +1 for TThread.Queue

Comment: Helping you solve this artificial problem doesn't sound like it will get you anywhere. What's the real problem?

Comment: @Gabr The idea of having 50 threads might be, indeed, wrong; but if they are all sleeping, like Rufo pointed out, well, I have no problems. However, I'll look out for TThread.Queue. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't understand your question. I have a problem, and because I respect your help a lot, I didn't post my whole software for you to get lost in it. I posted what would be of interest. And like I said, it's not _that_ much of a problem; however, I think my code is wrong. The solution could help other people with that kind of problem (threads all updating the interface every second)

Comment: I think we need to know a little more about the real problem. In my app I have a list view that reports progress in lots of different tasks, typically one per thread. I handle that with a single main thread timer that asks each thread for progress. I think that's going to be more scalable than your approach. But I don't know the real problem you have.

Comment: We have a similar approach as mentioned by @David, worker threads sends progress info into a thread-safe queue. This queue is drained by a consumer thread which posts the information to a list view.

Comment: @SirRufo - The question never states that threads are mostly sleeping. The code in the question is obviously a demo and I presumed that Sleep is actually replace with a workload in the true code.

Comment: @gabr I can't get your point from the question or the code. I just can answer to the points mentioned in the question. I'm not able to look at the OP monitor or into his brain :o) He should improve his question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have placed the cart ahead of the horse here. Having all your threads synchronize into the main thread, each with their own timer and message queue, will place a heavy burden on the system. What's more, often times you don't want to burden your threads with running a message loop.

A better approach in my view is to place a single timer in the main thread. When it ticks, have it retrieve progress from each thread or task that it needs to report on. You'll need to serialize access to that progress, but that's not expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I think threads are more expensive to the CPU than you might think.  From what I remember, the CPU has overhead to swap each thread in and out of the cache.  With the CPU swapping out 50 different threads, I'm not surprised its overloading

One solution might be to extend the TTimer component then dynamically create 50 of those rather than 50 threads.  TTimer uses the windows api instead of threads.  (The code below is untested, but should at least give you the idead)

```
TMyTimer = class(TTimer)
begin
  public
    Timer: integer;
    ListItem: TListItem;
end;
...
procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject)
begin
  for i := 0 to 50 do
  begin
     ltimer = TMyTimer.Create;
     ltimer.Timer := 300;
     ltimer.ListItem := TListItem.Create;
     //initialize list item here
     ltimer.OnTimer := DecTimer;
  end;
end;

procedure DecTimer(Sender: TObject)
begin
  dec(TMytimer(Sender).Timer);
  TMyTimer(Sender).ListItem.SubItem[1] := StrToInt(TMytimer(Sender).Timer)
end;
```

If the threads are all starting at the same time, try doing something like having one thread control up to 25 timer.  i.e. For 50 timers you only have two threads.  The timer event would then just loop through its 25 counters and decrement them.  You'd still need to use synchronize for this.

The answer to this question might be of interest:
[How expensive are threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429214/how-expensive-are-threads)

Comment: in the question I do not see a `TTimer`, only a timer - which seems to be a simple integer variable

Comment: I thought of it, but I've heard that TTimer can be unreliable as they are low priority to Windows. Is there any truth in that?

Comment: Timer events are low priority events.

Comment: I have applications using 200+ threads and there is no inherent problem. Wise use of them is of course sensible always.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example using `TThread.Queue` and a `TSimpleEvent` for timing the counter instead of a `Sleep()`.

```
Type
  TThreadWorker = Class(TThread)
  private
    FTimer : Integer;
    FListItem : TListItem;
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure UpdateTimer;
    procedure DeleteTicket;
  public
    constructor Create( aListItem : TListItem);
  End;

constructor TThreadWorker.Create(aListItem : TListItem);
begin
  Inherited Create(false);
  FListItem := aListItem;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := true;
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.Execute;
var
  anEvent : TSimpleEvent;
begin
  anEvent := TSimpleEvent.Create(nil,true,false,'');
  try
    FTimer := 300;
    repeat
      anEvent.WaitFor(1000);
      Queue(UpdateTimer);
      Dec(FTimer);
    until (FTimer = 0);
    Self.Synchronize( DeleteTicket); // <-- Do not Queue this !
  finally
    anEvent.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.UpdateTimer;
begin
  FListItem.SubItems[1] := IntToStr(FTimer);
end;

procedure TThreadWorker.DeleteTicket;
begin
  FListItem.Delete;
end;
```

Just a note, the `DeleteTicket` must be synchronized. The thread is terminated when execute is done, and anything on the queue will be left dangling.

Comment: Just to note, I would never mix up logical parts (here TThread) with the presentation part (here TListItem). And this is more to the OP than to @LURD :o)

Comment: DeleteTicket also could be moved to a [TThread.OnTerminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate) event handler (which will be executed in the context of the main thread)